# Under which conditions is $\int_\Gamma f=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Let $\Gamma$ be a contour. $V\subseteq \mathbb C$ and $f:V\rightarrow
>  \mathbb C$.
>
> What are the conditions on:
>
> - $\Gamma$
> - $f$
> - Open $U\subseteq V$
>
> such that $\int_\Gamma f=0$

This seems like an open mapping theorem which states that open sets get mapped to open sets.

**I thought:**

Let $f$ be holomorphic everywhere, let $\Gamma$ be a closed loop. $U$ to be anything. Is this correct?

Comment: $\Gamma$ closed and within $U$ and $f$ holomorphic on $U$ is enough.

Comment: @thanks, is it possible for an integral to be $0$ for any non-closed contours?

Comment: Looks too general to me, holomorphic f is sufficient but not necessary as $\Gamma$ is not general, it's about conditions on $\Gamma$ such that the statement is true.

Comment: @HenryW.: Not sufficient.  You also need $U$ to be simply connected, or at least, that $\Gamma$ has winding number 0 around the complement of $U$.  Standard counterexample: $U = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, $\Gamma$ the unit circle, $f(z)=1/z$.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the Cauchy integral theorem and you will get your answer

Comment: thanks, from the theorem I see that $V$ must be simply-connected and $f$ holomorphic on $V$. But since $U\subseteq V$, does that mean that I require $U=V$?

Comment: @ Sorry everyone,  my comment have no relation with the question,  @çiçek I work in the same field as you (Fixed point theory), and I want to contact you in MP, is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Integral around contours are computed with the residue formula. So the sum of the residues inside the contour must be zero. Take the Laurent development at each singular point in the contour and compute it's residue.